# Using browser.get with different webpage urls are loading the wrong url first

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, automation, protractor

I have a test that sends an email to mailinator from the baseurl defined in the config page. After the email is sent I then want to load mailinator to verify the email is there. What is happening however is protractor is loading www.mailinator.com instead of the baseurl.

I am calling mailinator like this below:

```
browser.get('www.mailinator.com');
```

Any idea how I can fix this?  I browsed some stackoverflow pages however I haven't found one that directly relates to what I'm asking.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if I got you right. You are asking browser to open www.mailinator.com page and you expect it to open some different page?

Comment: @Nicole: can you please be more specific about ur issue or what exactly u r trying to do?

Comment: @Piotr sorry if I am confusing no, I am opening up a page like this: https://iplan.newmarketinc.com and then later in the test I need to check if an email I send from that page is sent properly on mailinator. However mailinator loads instead of the baseurl which is the iplan page.

Comment: @Ignit I wrote above this comment a clearer way to state the issue, however i declared a param in my conf file that eliminated the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure I got you right.

1. Open website with

   browser.get('https://iplan.newmarketinc.com/');
2. Proceed with your test
3. At the point you need to verify if email was sent, go to mailinator with

   browser.get('www.mailinator.com');

Do the email verification. If you do not wish to leave your page on newmarketinc.com you can simply create new instance of webdriver for the purpose of getting to mailinator.

4. Go back to your test execution

Comment: Thank you for your answer however this is the original way I had been doing the browser loads however when I would kick of the tests it was loading mailinator instead of loading the baseURL.  I fixed this by making mailinator a param of my .conf file.